# Regarding homogeneous coordinates for real projective plane (specially point $(0,0,1)$)

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

We extend the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ by introducing points a infinity and a line at infinity.
Then we represent the extended Euclidean plane by homogeneous coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

(a) The points $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ are represented by points $(x,y,1)$.

(b) The points at infinity are represented by points of the form $(x,y,0)$.

(c) The line at infinity is represented by the point $(0,0,1)$.

The point $(0,0,1)$ also belongs to point (a) above.

So does $(0,0,1)$ represent both the point $(0,0)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the line at infinity?

I wanted to relate it to the homogeneous coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for the extended real line $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$. Where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ Corresponds to the point $(1,x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the point at infinity corresponds to the point $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos  But the line at infinity is represented by the vector (0,0,1) right.?

Comment: Yes. I deleted my comment because I didn't think about homogenous coordinates for lines, just those for points.

Comment: It's a nice idea for notation to represent your homogeneous coordinates in $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as $(x:y:z)$, the colons differentiating them from points in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of the projective plane as the set of all lines through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$. So every line through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$ is a point in $\mathbb RP^2$, and every plane through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$ is a line in $\mathbb RP^2$.

Every line in $\mathbb R^3$ is defined by two points. In this case, the origin and one additional point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\neq(0,0,0)$. The coordinates of this additional point are the homogenous coordinates of that line as a point in $\mathbb RP^2$. We can embed the affine plane $\mathbb R^2$ into this projective plane by identifying $(x,y)$ with the line that goes through the point $(x,y,1)$. In other words, the homogenous coordinates of the point $(x,y)$ from the affine plane are $(x,y,1)$. The newly added points at infinity are the lines in $\mathbb R^3$ which do not go through a point of the form $(x,y,1)$, so the ones which do not intersect the plane $z=1$. In other words, the lines which are parallel to the $x-y$-plane, and thus go through a point of the form $(x,y,0)$. This is why the points at infinity have homogenous coordinates $(x,y,0)$.

Now to the line at infinity: As I said at the beginning, lines in $\mathbb RP^2$ are planes through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$. But planes through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$ are uniquely defined by a line through the origin which is perpendicular to said plane. But those lines are already the points in $\mathbb RP^2$. So there is a certain duality between points and lines in $\mathbb RP^2$: If we take a line in $\mathbb RP^2$, we can view it as a plane in $\mathbb R^3$, which is definable through a line in $\mathbb R^3$ perpendicular to said plane, and the line can again be interpreted as a point in $\mathbb RP^2$.

The line at infinity consists of all the points at infinity. In $\mathbb R^3$, this corresponds to all lines through the origin parallel to the $x-y$-plane. Together, they form the $x-y$-plane. The line perpendicular to this plane is the one pointing only in the $z$-direction, in other words, the one through the point $(0,0,1)$. So the line at infinity in $\mathbb RP^2$ can be identified with the line through the origin and $(0,0,1)$ in $\mathbb R^3$, which in turn can be identified with the point $(0,0,1)$ (homogenous coordinates) in $\mathbb RP^2$.

And that's why both the line at infinity and the origin in the projective plane have the same homogenous coordinates: $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Ok. So is the extended Euclidean plane embedded inside the projective plane or is it identified with it?

Comment: @user534666: They are one and the same. Projective plane just sounds fancier.

Comment: Ok... so... the line at infinity contains all the points at infinity which are already represented by the homogeneous coordinates (x,y,0). The homogeneous coordinate (0,0,1) is another way of representing the line at infinity as a ‘line’. Am I correct?

Comment: @user534666: You don't really represent it as a line. Rather, you characterize it using a line by saying that as a plane in $\mathbb R^3$, the line at infinity is perpendicular to a certain line in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Actually I wanted to ask.... so the representation of the   extended Euclidean plane requires only the homogeneous coordinates of the form (x,y,z) where $z\neq 0$ in union with the homogeneous coordinates of the form (x,y,0). [Basically the second paragraph of your answer]?

Comment: Yes. All other homogeneous coordinates are just duplicates. Like $(x,y,1)$ and $(2x,2y,2)$ represent the same point. (Now I get what you meant by represent!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111138/discussion-between-user534666-and-vercassivelaunos).